# Wikidata SPARQL How to get a list of TV series that a given actor in its cast members

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I try to get the filmography of a given actor include films, TV series.
For example, to get list of films with Zhao Wei I used the [query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Ffilm%20%3FpubDate%20%3FfilmLabel%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ11424%20.%0A%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP577%20%3FpubDate%20.%0A%20%20%20%3Ffilm%20wdt%3AP161%20wd%3AQ233859%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%20ORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3FpubDate%29%0ALIMIT%2050) but it can not list TV series.

How can I get TV series too. Or how can I list the cast members of a TV series?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?film ?pubDate ?filmLabel WHERE {
   ?film wdt:P31 wd:Q11424 .
   ?film wdt:P577 ?pubDate .
   ?film wdt:P161 wd:Q197471 .
  SERVICE wikibase:label {
    bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" .
  }
 } ORDER BY DESC(?pubDate)
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Do you have an example TV series that exists in Wikidata for the given actor? The Wikidata type to query for would be `wd:Q21191270` but for your actor, no results are returned. So I don't know if this data really exists. That's why I'm asking for an example series that you know to be contained in Wikidata.

Comment: I think it should be because I find Q21191270 usually have no cast member information
`{
 ?film (p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279*) wd:Q11424.
}
UNION {
 ?film p:P31/ps:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q5398426 .
}
UNION {
 # Q3464665 TV series season/Q21191270 TV series episode
 ?film wdt:P361 wd:Q5398426 .
}`

Answer (score 0):

This work for Will Smith: Q40096. It returns movies like "Men in Black", and TV Shows like "Fresh Prince of Bel-Air".

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P161 wd:Q40096.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```